# Difference between Proxmark3 rdv4 & Proxmark3 evo

Tags: tools

I am an advanced beginner in RFID/NFC reversing / hacking. For now, I have a mifare reader and I want to buy a better reader to able to perform advanced stuffs on both HF and LF (especially emulation and cloning).

I've read on multiple websites about the Proxmark3 evo and Proxmark3 rdv4. I am wondering what the differences are in terms of what I can do with the rdv4 that I can't with the Evo version.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the same with Proxmark3 Evo and Proxmark3 RDV4. The only difference is that the hardware of the Proxmark3 RDV4 is more advanced than the Evo.